# Is it possible in JS to get an object , assign value to property send it to another function in one line?

Tags: javascript, object

here is piece of JS code:

```
function getObj(){
    return {p1: "None"};
}

function printObj(obj){
    console.log(obj.p1);
}
//Create an object  
let o = getObj();

// Assign val
o.p1 = "Val2";

//send to Print
printObj(o);
```

Is it possible to do the same in one short line  - something like the following ?

```
printObj(getObj().p1 = "Val1");
```

*****Edit*****
In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65789589/js-performance-compare-simple-task-4-different-ways-surprising-results)  wrote short code to compare the different approaches.

Comment: `printObj(Object.assign(getObj(), { p1: 'Val1' }));` ... this approach directly changes the return value of `getObj()`; thus skipping the creation of yet another object like one does with e.g. `{ ...getObj(), p1: "Val1" }` with the latter being similar to `Object.assign({}, getObj(), { p1: 'Val1' })`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I wrote some short code to speed wise compare, the different ways. Posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65789589/js-performance-compare-simple-task-4-different-ways-surprising-results). Looks like `{ p1: 'Val1' }` also creates an object as has been properly mentioned there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use spread operator, which will get an object from your function and generate a new object with all of your object fields.
Than all that's left is to override the prop

```
printObj({...getObj(), p1: "Val1"});
```

```js
function getObj(){
    return {p1: "None"};
}

function printObj(obj){
    console.log(obj.p1);
}
//Create an object  
let o = getObj();

// Assign val
o.p1 = "Val2";

//send to Print
printObj(o);

//all in one line
printObj({...getObj, p1: "Val2"});
```

Comment: `p1: "Val1"`, `=` isn't valid there.

Comment: @OrYaacov Is it better though in terms of efficiency and speed? what's the better way - this solution or the simple 3 lines of code approach?