# JS performance compare - simple task, 4 different ways. surprising results?

Tags: javascript, performance

**The simple task:**
get an object, override its property, and send to another function.

I compared 4 approaches for that:

**#1 - the "simple way":**

```
let o = getObj();
o.p1 = "Val2";
doSomethingWithObj(o);
```

**#2 Using Spread operator:**

```
doSomethingWithObj({ ...getObj(), p1: "Val2" });
```

**#3 Using Spread operator  - a bit different:**

```
let o = { ...getObj(), p1: "Val2" };
doSomethingWithObj(o);
```

**#4 Using Object.Assign():**

```
doSomethingWithObj(Object.assign(getObj(), { p1: 'Val2' }));
```

Single test execution contains creation of 50,000 objects is each approach.
Test is repeated 5 times.
I used the browser performance interface to measure executions times.
Tested on FireFox and Operas well as the snippet here, added below (running in Opera).

```js
const repeat = 50000;
test();

function test(){

    let times = 5;

    let summary = {};

    //Loop to execute (times)
    for (let i = 1; i<=times; i++){
        
        console.log(`Execution #${i}`);
        let res = runSingleTest();

        //sum results of current execution 
        Object.keys(res).forEach((key)=>
                    (summary[key] 
                    ? summary[key] += res[key] 
                    : summary[key] = res[key] )
                );
        
    }

    //Log full results
    console.log(`Total time of ${times} executions`);
    console.log(summary);
}

/**
 *  Single test do:
 *  1. simple way
 *  2. using spread operator 
 *  3. using spread operator 2
 *  4. using Object.assign
 */
function runSingleTest() {
    //Assign arrow function to f
    let f = (handler,startName,endName,measureName) => 
            {
                //start mark
                window.performance.mark(startName);
                //Execute test
                handler();
                window.performance.mark(endName);
                window.performance.measure(measureName, startName, endName);
            }

    // execute tests supplying different handler and performance strings
    f(simpleWay,"simpleWayStart","simpleWayEnd","simpleWayTiming");
    f(usingSpread1,"spreadStart1","spreadEnd1","spreadTiming1");
    f(usingSpread2,"spreadStart2","spreadEnd2","spreadTiming2");
    f(usingObjAssign,"assignStart","assignEnd","assignTiming");

    //Log results
    let result = {};
    performance.getEntriesByType("measure").forEach(
        element => {result[element.name] = element.duration });
    
    console.log(result);
    //Clear 
    performance.clearMarks();
    performance.clearMeasures();
    return result;
}

// oldStyle
function simpleWay() {
    for (let i = 1; i < repeat; i++) {
        let o = getObj();
        o.p1 = "Val2";
        doSomethingWithObj(o);
    }
}

// usingSpread1
function usingSpread1() {
    for (let i = 1; i < repeat; i++) {
        doSomethingWithObj({ ...getObj(), p1: "Val2" });
    }
}

// usingSpread2
function usingSpread2() {
    for (let i = 1; i < repeat; i++) {
        let o = { ...getObj(), p1: "Val2" };
        doSomethingWithObj(o);
    }
}

// usingObjAssign
function usingObjAssign() {
    for (let i = 1; i < repeat; i++) {
        doSomethingWithObj(Object.assign(getObj(), { p1: 'Val2' }));
    }
}

function doSomethingWithObj(obj) {
    return obj.p1;
}

function getObj(){
    return {p1: "None"};
}
```

**Results:**
Simple old way - big time win.
it has significantly better performance than the short handed writing.
I was thinking it will be the opposite, that the JS short writing comes with better performance, but somehow it looks not so true.
[image: Results]

Comments?

Comment: Thats not surprising at all. Methods 2, 3 and 4 are creating new objects, whereas method 1 is modifiying an existing object.

Comment: The _"simple way"_ just adds a new property. The others create new objects from a shallow copy of the original object. Why should they be faster?

Comment: @derpirscher as I have zero experience with JS I thought shorter syntax will come with "shorter" performance. NOT the opposite. While developing something I needed such a task. the first code was method 1. this is what I am used too. Then I thought about a more  "JS way". But it it come with worse performance - than why?

Comment: @derpirscher also I thought the way I used Object.Assign is not creating another object.

Comment: @OJNSim Oh, you are using the the object as first parameter of Object.assign. I misread that. But still, `Object.assign` has to iterate all properties of the second object and make (shallow) copies of the values, which produces some overhead over just assigning a single property.

Comment: "_short writing comes with better performance_" Not necessarily, performance (speed-wise in this case) depends on the JS engine and how it optimizes the code. Not a very long time ago, the fastest way to iterate an array was backwards with a `while` loop, all the implementations of `forEach` were magnitudes slower. What comes to your test, the parts are doing different things, tests #2 - #4 are all creating an extra object and are also forced to iterate one of those objects internally, whereas #1 just adds a property to an existing object. That's also "the most JS way", if that matters.

Comment: @OJNSim "*I thought the way I used Object.Assign is not creating another object.*" - `{ p1: 'Val2' }` is still an object that get created. It's static, so it's *possible* for the engine to remove it and only keep a single object but it also may not. Also, `assign` will do a lot more work than simply copying one property - it will attempt to copy all properties, so even then it has the added overhead of trying to fetch all defined property descriptors on both objects being merged.

Comment: @Teemu #4 is not creating another object, this was the purpose in the first place - **not creating another object**. However, I do understand what you (and others) are saying, and despite my wrong assumption - I see (again) there is nothing free. The shorter code in many cases will usually comes with price behind.

Comment: @OJNSim VLAZ has just explained above how #4 creates a new object.

Comment: @VLAZ you are right. my mistake.